# SSD NVME RAID0 MDADM

Tags: raid0, nvme

My goal is to obtain good writing performances on SSD NVME Disks (benchmarking tools seem to give performances in specific optimized context but far from what we can obtained in real life)

My server: 
32x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4110 CPU @ 2.10GHz
RAM : 256GB DDR4
HD : 2x 1,5TB SSD NVME MICRON 9200 => RAID0
HD : 1x 1,5TB SSD NVME MICRON 9200 => DISK1
OS : debian 9.5
file system : XFS

I am using cp and dd to measure bandwidth of files copy from RAMDISK (30Go of /dev/urandom) to DISK1 and to RAID0
I am monitoring the writing operation with iostat
I am using bs=1M and oflag with dd

a) with dd from RAMDisk to RAID0 
without oflag=direct I get 15Gb/s 
and with oflag=direct I get nearly 20Gb/s. GOOD!

b) with dd from RAMDisk to DISK1 
without oflag=direct I get 15Gb/s 
and with I get 13 Gb/s. I am not sure to understand the inversion

c) with cp from RAMDisk to RAID0, performances are poor and iostat samples every 2s shows 4 seconds without write between each write on RAID0

What is the best way to measure RAID0 SSD NVME in a realistic way without fluctuation)

Kind regards

Comment: I think 15Gbps for a single disk is not possible. Make sure you sync to clear write buffer after the dd copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use FIO for testing the storage and send fstrim command to the RAID-0 SSD pool prior to tests.
Links for ref -

https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio or https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://www.linux.com/learn/inspecting-disk-io-performance-fio

http://blog.neutrino.es/2013/howto-properly-activate-trim-for-your-ssd-on-linux-fstrim-lvm-and-dmcrypt/